# Output from SAS CEM macro for measuring average treatment effect on variable of interest Y?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm running Gary King's CEM (Coarsened Exact Matching) macro (download [here](https://gking.harvard.edu/cem)) in the SAS language for a case control study. I'm using the following macro call format:

```
options source2;
%include "D:\Project_Files\Matched_Cohort_Study\CEM_SAS_Macro.sas";

%CEM (
    lib = out, 
    dataset = analysis_data, 
    id = MEMBER_ID, 
    treat = A, 
    keep = X1 X2 X3,
    del_miss = 0,
    match_type = N, 
    method = "Sturges", 
    path_graph = D:\Project_Files\Matched_Cohort_Study\,
    report = "on"
      );
```

The macro runs without error, but where is the matched output dataset I can use to estimate the average treatment effect on my outcome variable Y?

Comment: Run it with MPRINT option on and see what it does.

Answer (score 1):

From looking over the macro, it looks like the output dataset is in `&lib.` and is called `L1_finale`; see if that exists and has what you expect in it.

Comment: Thanks for checking the code - I see where L1_finale is created in the macro, but I don't see L1_finale in the &lib folder.

Comment: I'd guess your macro didn't run properly then, but it's hard to say for sure without seeing the log...

Comment: Problem solved - I had duplicate member IDs in my data. Once I created unique IDs for each record the macro ran fine.